# Is `getlogin()` implemented by reading from `/var/run/utmp`?

Tags: c, linux, gnu-coreutils

From https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/268388/674

> `logname` goes up the user that owns the `tty` (by reading it from `/var/run/utmp`)

In [the source code of coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html), I find that `logname.c` is implemented based on Linux API function `getlogin`:

```
#include <unistd.h>
char *getlogin(void);
```

I don't find `/var/run/tmp` in `logname.c`.

Is `getlogin()` implemented by reading from `/var/run/utmp`?

Thanks.

---

On my Lubuntu 18.04, `strace logname` does output:

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/var/run/utmp", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to find out whether `logname` looks at `/var/run/utmp` is by running it under `strace`, like this:

```
$ strace -e trace=open,openat logname 2>&1 | grep -Ev '\.so\.[0-9]+", O_RD'
```

The `-e trace=open,openat` part makes it only print calls to `open` (and `openat`, which glibc really likes to use internally) and the `grep` filters out opening of shared libraries.  That cuts down the output enough that I can actually explain it coherently:

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/self/loginuid", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/nsswitch.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
zack
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

So, on my system, the files it opened were `/etc/ld.so.cache` and `/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive`, both of which contain generic data that has nothing to do with `getlogin`; `/proc/self/loginuid`, which, it seems, contains my user ID, I don't know where that's documented; `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, which tells the C library where to look for the mapping of user IDs to names; and `/etc/passwd`, which (on my system) contains that mapping.  It did *not* look in `/var/run/utmp` at any point.

(The value in `/proc/self/loginuid` will be different from the value returned by `getuid` if you use `su` to impersonate another user, for instance; `su root -c logname` still prints "zack" for me.)

However, if I make it impossible for `logname` to look at `/proc/self/loginuid` (by temporarily bind-mounting an empty directory over `/proc`) then I get something different.  (I'm cheating a little here: I ran `strace` without any `-e` option in order to find out which system calls would be relevant.  Also I manually edited the output down even further.)

```
$ strace -e trace=access,fstat,ioctl,open,openat,readlink,stat logname 2>&1 |
     grep -Ev '\.so\.[0-9]+", O_RD'
...
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/self/loginuid", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT
ioctl(0, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
fstat(0, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 1), ...}) = 0
readlink("/proc/self/fd/0", 0x7ffd2adfb030, 511) = -1 ENOENT
stat("/dev/pts/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/pts/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
stat("/dev/pts/1", {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 1), ...}) = 0
close(3)                                = 0
access("/var/run/utmpx", F_OK)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/var/run/utmp", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
...
logname: no login name
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

If it can't open `/proc/self/loginuid`, then it goes to some length to find the name of the terminal associated with its own stdin (the easy way, `readlink("/proc/self/fd/0")`, doesn't work because I whited out all of `/proc` for this test) and then it *does* look that up in `/var/run/utmp`, after first determining that  `/var/run/utmpx` doesn't exist.  (That's a bug; testing whether a file you're about to open already exists has an inherent [TOCTOU race](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use).  It should just open it and check whether open failed.)  And it doesn't find an entry, so it fails.  This is because the Linux distribution I use (sp. Debian unstable) has decided that it's silly for every single terminal window to have its own utmp entry, there should be just one for my entire X session, whether or not I have any terminals open:

```
$ who
zack     :0           2018-05-30 17:37 (:0)
```

A break with tradition, but a sensible one, I think.

Comment: Thanks. Remember that `setrlimit()` doesn't read from `/etc/security/limits.conf`.  If it is true that `getlogin()` reads from `/var/run/utmp` or some file else, is `/var/run/utmp` a configuration file of `getlogin()`?

Comment: @Tim No, because `/var/run/utmp` is not a _configuration_ file; it's more of a tiny database (in fact, its official name is "the database of active logins").  But the functions that (may) look at `/var/run/utmp` do have much more in common with the functions that (may) look at `/etc/passwd` (e.g. `getpwnam`), which _is_ a configuration file, than with the resource limit controls.

Answer (score 2):

`getlogin` is not a Linux API function but a libc function, and on GNU/Linux with glibc it's [implemented here](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/getlogin_r.c;h=14587712a72ecd0bb1aec4d131f4047a60cc134c;hb=HEAD#l36):

```
   /* Try to determine login name from /proc/self/loginuid and return 0
      if successful.  If /proc/self/loginuid cannot be read return -1.
      Otherwise return the error number.  */

   int
   attribute_hidden
   __getlogin_r_loginuid (char *name, size_t namesize)
   {
     int fd = __open_nocancel ("/proc/self/loginuid", O_RDONLY);
  [...]
```

This is also evident from `strace`:

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/self/loginuid", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "1000", 12)                     = 4
close(3)                                = 0
```

So no, `/usr/bin/logname` does not read from the file `/var/run/utmp`.

Answer (score 1):

The [glibc code](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/getlogin.c.html#getlogin) is a bit of a maze.  But the easy way to determine what any program does at the userspace-kernel interface, which includes any reading of files, is the [`strace`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) utility.

When I ran `strace logname` just now, it included the output:

> ```
> open("/var/run/utmp", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
> lseek(3, 0, SEEK_SET)                   = 0
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
> read(3, "\2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0~\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 384) = 384
> read(3, "\1\0\0\0005\0\0\0~\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 384) = 384
> read(3, "\6\0\0\0\302\5\0\0tty1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 384) = 384
> read(3, "\7\0\0\0\230\7\0\0tty7\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 384) = 384
> read(3, "", 384)                        = 0
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
> close(3)                                = 0
> ```

So yes, `/usr/bin/logname` reads from the file `/var/run/utmp`.

Comment: Is this a distro difference? I looked on Debian Stable ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.4, and `strace logname` shows it opens `/proc/self/loginuid` then `/etc/passwd`, then does a readlink on `/proc/self/fd/0`, then opens `/var/run/utmp`.  `sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/getlogin.c` does sound like a more appropriate file than `sysdeps/unix/getlogin.c` though.  I'm guessing the `/var/run/utmp` access happens via the `__getpwuid_r`. @thatotherguy

Comment: Indeed, glibc is a goddamn maze. The file containing the code that actually opens `/var/run/utmp` is `login/utmp_file.c` ... but there's a file named `sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/utmp_file.c` that _modifies_ that file (by defining macros and then #include-ing it).  Similarly, the code in `sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/getlogin.c` uses the code in  `sysdeps/unix/getlogin.c` as a fallback.  It took me an embarrasingly long time to figure this all out, and I actually hack on glibc in my copious free time.

Comment: Regarding `/proc/self/loginuid` - on my Debian testing system I see `pam_loginuid.so` in the `/etc/pam.d` configuration.  So maybe if that's configured, it sets the process attribute to be inherited by processes, so `logname` can use that, but it not, it has to fall back to reading `/var/run/utmp`?